# sort by relation laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I need sort products by certain attribute id and his value. I have model Product with relation:

```
public function attribute()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\ProductAttribute');
}
```

ProductAttribute model have:

```
public function attribute()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\AttributeValue', 'attribute_value_id');
}
```

I need sort products where attribute_id = 5 and with all values of this attribute. I try do this:

```
$products = Product::active()->where(function($query) {
     $query->whereHas('attribute.attribute', function($q) {
         $q->where('attribute_id', 5)->orderBy('value', 'desc');
     });
})->get();
```

But this is not working.

Structure table of model Product Attribute:

- id
- attribute_value_id
- product_id

Structure table of model AttributeValue:

- id
- attribute_id
- value

In value can be numeric values.
Please help me resolve this problem.

Comment: you need to use join on the relation instead of loading it like that, right now you are ordering the relation not the "Products".

Answer (score 0):

You should use joins:

```
$products = Product::active()
    ->select('products.*')
    ->leftJoin('product_attribute', 'product_attribute.product_id', '=', 'products.id')
    ->leftJoin('attribute_values', function($query){
        $query
            ->on('attribute_values.id', '=', 'product_attribute.attribute_value_id')
            ->where('attribute_id', '5');
    })
    ->groupBy('products.id')
    ->orderByDesc('attribute_values.value');
```

Not sure about table names.